# How to coefmatrix in maxima

Tags: maxima

I have a 3x3 matrix. I am trying to separate out the variables from the constants in my matrix. I am aware I can use the function `coefmatrix`

Function: coefmatrix ([eqn_1, …, eqn_m], [x_1, …, x_n])

```
t1: Xd_x . Ta . Xdd_x;
```

[image: t1]

```
q: list_matrix_entries(Xd_x . Ta . Xdd_x );
```

How to get the coefficient matrix for q with unknowns `Ta(*,*)`?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of experimenting, I could figure this out.

Following will do the trick. The important point is the matrix q need to be linear in the coefficients and make sure all the coefficients are given into 2nd argument.

```
A: coefmatrix( q, [Ta_00, Ta_01, Ta_02, Ta_10, Ta_11, Ta_12, Ta_20, Ta_21, Ta_22 ] )
```